# How to store values to variable after while loop ends in php so that i can use that variables in other query?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$efind = $_SESSION['email'];
require('mysqli_connect.php');

$sql = "SELECT userid,fname,lname,email,phone,adds FROM userst where email ='$efind'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    // What to write here ?
}
```

I want to store the `userid`, `fname`, `lname`, `email`, `phone`, `adds` that are fetched from the loop but when I echo the variables they don't have any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 $sql = "SELECT userid,fname,lname,email,phone,adds FROM userst where email ='$efind'";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
            $firstName  = '';
            $lastName  = '';


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $firstName  = $row['fname'];
                $lastName  = $row['lname'];;
            }
```